# Why does the HotSpot ExecutionSample event always return STATE_RUNNABLE?

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot, jfr

I'm using the [ExecutionSample event](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/999dbd4192d0f819cb5224f26e9e7fa75ca6f289/src/hotspot/share/jfr/metadata/metadata.xml#L702) from HotSpot in OpenJDK11.

It has a field for thread state, but I only ever see one value for the field: `STATE_RUNNABLE`

How does HotSpot choose which threads to sample? Why are they always runnable?

Simple reproduction code in Kotlin:

```
import jdk.jfr.Recording
import jdk.jfr.consumer.RecordingFile
import java.nio.file.Path

object ExecutionSampleTest {

    private const val EXECUTION_SAMPLE = "jdk.ExecutionSample"
    private val RECORDING_PATH = Path.of("/tmp/recording.jfr")

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        Recording().use { recording ->
            recording.enable(EXECUTION_SAMPLE)
            recording.settings = recording.settings.plus("$EXECUTION_SAMPLE#period" to "1 ms")

            recording.start()
            repeat(100) {
                // start some sleeping threads, just so we've got something to sample
                Thread { Thread.sleep(20_000) }.start()
            }
            Thread.sleep(20_000)
            recording.stop()
            recording.dump(RECORDING_PATH)

            RecordingFile.readAllEvents(RECORDING_PATH).forEach {
                println("Thread state: ${it.getString("state")}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Only ever prints: `Thread state: STATE_RUNNABLE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does the HotSpot ExecutionSample event always return STATE_RUNNABLE?

By design.

JFR method profiler periodically samples Java threads and produces two types of events:

- `ExecutionSample`, when a thread state is `in_java`
- `NativeMethodSample`, when a thread state is `in_native`

See [jfrThreadSampler.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/c01bc48cfcbe/src/hotspot/share/jfr/periodic/sampling/jfrThreadSampler.cpp#l369) source code:

```
  if (JAVA_SAMPLE == type) {
    if (thread_state_in_java(thread)) {
      ret = sample_thread_in_java(thread, frames, max_frames);
    }
  } else {
    assert(NATIVE_SAMPLE == type, "invariant");
    if (thread_state_in_native(thread)) {
      ret = sample_thread_in_native(thread, frames, max_frames);
    }
  }
```

Both `in_java` and `in_native` correspond to `STATE_RUNNABLE` in JFR format.

When a thread is not runnable for either reason (`STATE_SLEEPING`, `STATE_PARKED` etc.), its JVM state is `thread_blocked`. However, JFR method profiler does not sample blocked threads at all.

---

If you are interested in wall clock profiling (i.e. sampling *all* threads, whether they run on CPU or sleep), you may want to look at [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/). Async-profiler can also produce output in JFR compatible format, but unlike JFR, it generates `ExecutionSample` events both for RUNNABLE and IDLE threads.

Comment: Thanks! Does the sampling then happen independently of safepoints, since my reading of the source code indicates that sampling happens via an OS signal? If so, do I get value from adding `-XX:+DebugNonSafepoints` to generate symbols for the samples which land between safepoints?

Edit: I think I found the answer (yes) at https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-5/jfr-runtime-guide/about.htm#JFRRT110

Comment: @CuriousJavaGuy Right. JFR collects samples not only at safepoints, and therefore `-XX:+DebugNonSafepoints` can improve profile accuracy.